# How can I setup eshell to use ivy for tab completion?

Tags: eshell, ivy

I'm very fond of `ivy` for completion and love that a simple `(ivy-mode 1)` is enough to get `ivy` almost everywhere that Emacs uses some sort of completion (that is acomplished by overriding `completeing-read`, I believe). But this doesn't setup `eshell` to use `ivy` for tab completion. I do like `eshell`'s list of completion candidates, but would prefer the `ivy` UI to pick among them. Is there some way to reuse whatever `eshell` does to produce completion candidates and hand that off to `ivy'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
(define-key eshell-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") 'completion-at-point)
```

I don't know why the above isn't the default. But I use only `shell-mode` and `term-mode` anyway.

Comment: You should probably add that `(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook           '(lambda ()` needs to be wrapped around it.

Comment: Thanks, that's a little neater than what I had. The reason it's not the default is probably just that someone at some point in the past prefered `pcomplete` over the standard completion UI.

Answer (score 6):

I found something that seems to work OK upon initial testing: essentially rebind `<tab>` to `pcomplete-std-complete`, but since that function isn't interactive for some reason, you need to wrap it:

```
(define-key eshell-mode-map (kbd "<tab>")
  (lambda () (interactive) (pcomplete-std-complete)))
```

The `pcompete-std-complete` tries to use the completions written for `pcomplete` with the standard completion UI, which `ivy` by default will override (with the very recent update, they appear in a nice overlay right in the eshell buffer near point!).

The comments in the source code of `pcomplete-completions-at-point` (which `pcomplete-std-complete` depends on) mention a couple of potential problems:

```
;; FIXME: it only completes the text before point, whereas the
;; standard UI may also consider text after point.
;; FIXME: the `pcomplete' UI may be used internally during
;; pcomplete-completions and then throw to `pcompleted', thus
;; imposing the pcomplete UI over the standard UI.
```

I think the first one won't affect me, since I don't think I ever press `<tab>` except at the end of the input line. I haven't seen the second problem surface either, so far.

EDIT: For those unfamiliar with eshell's quirks (this is a euphemism), maybe I should add that to rebind eshell's key as suggested above you should put this in your init file:

```
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
  (lambda () 
    (define-key eshell-mode-map (kbd "<tab>")
      (lambda () (interactive) (pcomplete-std-complete)))))
```

Before you yell at me for the wasteful keybindings-in-a-hook antipattern, let me explain that eshell declares its keymap with `(defvar eshell-mode-map nil)` and then does `(setq-local eshell-mode-map (sparse-keymap))` inside `eshell-mode`! (The code has a helpful `;; FIXME: What the hell!?`.) That means that you can't rebind keys until after `eshell-mode` runs! Hence the hook.

Comment: Also, I haven't tested it, but I would guess that if `helm` doesn't already insinuate its way into `eshell` tab completion, this fix also applies to `helm`.

Comment: This is pretty neat :) Thanks for the tip

Comment: That “What the he'll!?” comment made my day :) Also, I'd like to note this should also work for other completion frameworks, like helm.